# How to implement this UI: In a fragment there is a viewpager and inside the viewpager, there are three individual fragment

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I hope to implement this:

In a Fragment(with other three Fragment belongs to a activity), there is a ViewPager, and inside the ViewPager there are three Fragment, each Fragmnt contains its own ListView or GridView, and in this ListView or GridView, it will review the data from MySQL by JSON.

I am really confused about how to implement this.

I have implement one that the ViewPager is contained in a Activity and there are three Fragments inside the ViewPager and have its own listView.

also, there is some confict between the listview and viewpager that i don't know how to solve it.

can anyone give me a source code about this design and i can learn how to learn and implement it by myself.

ADD: i have no enough reputation to add a image. so a provide the website [here](http://blog.csdn.net/singwhatiwanna/article/details/17201587) and you can see which UI design I want (it's a chinese website and you just need to see the image not he words)

in this demo, all the three fragment is in a MainActivity, but what i want is in a parent Fragment.

Comment: Is it like you want a view pager with 3 Fragments inside that view pager and each fragment has a listview. I don't understand that if you just want listviews inside fragments, why to even use a viewpager in the first place ? why not in a layout, use three different fragments and in each fragment you have a listview.

Comment: but i need to slide left and right to choose which fragment displayed to the users, i edit my question and there is a image shows which UI design i want, there is little different, the design in the image is in a MainActivity, people can slide left and right to choose which fragment to display, but what i want is in a Fragment(not MainACtivity)